# Java 8 Lambdas - how to conditionally reset variable before populating

Tags: java, json, lambda

I am trying to use a lambda in Java for populating a `JSONArray` based on condition derived inside the lambda, basically if condition x is met I need to clear down the `JSONArray` and reset the value, otherwise append the values onto the `JSONArray`. However this does not seem possible given the effectively final variable required for lambdas - anyone able to advise, below is my attempt which gives me the "Variable should be final or effectively final" message:

```
JSONObject myObject = paramObj.getJSONObject(X);
JSONArray myArray = myObject.getJSONArray(VALUE);
if (myArray != null)
{
    myList.forEach(code -> {
        if (myCondition.equalsIgnoreCase(TEST))
        {
            myArray = new JSONArray();
            myArray.put(code);
        }
        else
        {
            myArray.put(code);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which package does `JSONArray` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming you are using [this implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf230/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONArray.html) of* `JSONArray`...

Make the array `final`, and rather than replace it with a new array instance, simply clear it before you add the new item.

```
final JSONObject myObject = paramObj.getJSONObject(X);
final JSONArray myArray = myObject.getJSONArray(VALUE);
if (myArray != null)
{
    myList.forEach(code -> {
        if (myCondition.equalsIgnoreCase(TEST))
        {
            while(myArray.length() > 0)
            {
                myArray.remove(0);
            } 
            myArray.put(code);
        }
        else
        {
            myArray.put(code);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If JSONArray internally uses an ArrayList, this code will *not* delete all items from the list. Instead probably what you want is
while(myArray.length() > 0) { myArray.remove(0);}

Comment: @digvijay91 In fact I think it probably would have removed everything but then would have overflowed. Your version is safer so I've edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the array is one option, however in cases where you do in fact need to create a new object you may use this method.

You can define some kind of a "Carrier" object, make that final and then put the JSONArray inside of it. In the simplest case an array of JSONArrays (could also be a list or your custom object containing a reference to a JSONArray) eg:

```
final JSONObject myObject = paramObj.getJSONObject(X);
final JSONArray [] myArray = new JSONArray[]{myObject.getJSONArray(VALUE)};
if (myArray[0] != null)
{
    myList.forEach(code -> {
        if (myCondition.equalsIgnoreCase(TEST))
        {
            myArray[0] = new JSONArray();
            myArray[0].put(code);
        }
        else
        {
            myArray[0].put(code);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the simple foreach? (With slightly cleaned up code)

```
JSONObject myObject = paramObj.getJSONObject(X);
JSONArray myArray = myObject.getJSONArray(VALUE);
if (myArray != null) {
   for (Object code : myList) {
      if (myCondition.equalsIgnoreCase(TEST)) {
         myArray = new JSONArray();  
      }
      myArray.put(code);
   }
}
```

Avoid unnecessarily littering your code with remove() and the possible O(n) complexity of remove (depending upon how it is implemented).